# Can i obtain three.js src files with bower?

Tags: symfony, three.js, dependencies, installation, bower

## Orignial:

I am developing a Symfony2 application with own vendor bundles.
I have installed `SpBowerBundle`.
All is fine, but I need the `objectLoader.js` (and some other files) from mrdoob his three.js library (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/loaders).

Is there any possibility to obtain these files through bower ?

## EDIT 1:

@Wilt This helped me a lot. But i don't want to download the whole package ^^

Now i have:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "three.js": "0.78.0",
"ObjectLoader.js": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/r78/src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js",
  },
...
```

Is there a way to make a repository like:

```
...
"repositories" : [{
    "type" : "git",
    "url" : "https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js"
}]
...
```

and add a dependency like:

```
"ObjectLoader.js": "0.78.0",
```

Comment: Not clear to me what you are asking.  Composer coexists nicely with bower or npm.  You just need a process to copy the files from the bower directory to your web directory.  I use a simple gulp file but there are plenty of other ways.  Though I suspect you are asking for something completely different.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full three.js library into your project with bower like this:

```
{
  "name": "your application",
  "version": "1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "three.js": "https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git#r78",
    ...
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

In principle bower is intended for getting a whole package/repository, but there is a workaround to get a single file like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "threejs-objectloader":  "https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js"
}
```